# How to change the number of reference of superscript to a normal size

Tags: cross-referencing, superscripts

I am using [this](https://pt.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-american-journal-of-undergraduate-research-ajur/xnfytcqzqvzc) template in Overleaf and I want to do a reference, but what appears is

[image],

but I would like to appear

> Based on the references [1] and [2].

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Remove the definition "`\bibpunct{}{}{,~}{s}{,}{,}`" in your files and compile twice you will get the requested output.